# Changing the TreeView ItemsPanel orientation has no effect

Tags: silverlight, treeview

The default `ItemsPanel` of a `TreeView` is a `StackPanel` that has the default orientation `Vertical`. I have changed the orientation of the `StackPanel` to `Horizontal`:

```
<controls:TreeView>
  <controls:TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </controls:TreeView.ItemsPanel>
  <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Root" IsExpanded="True">
    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Alfa"/>
    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Beta"/>
    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Gamma"/>
  </controls:TreeViewItem>
</controls:TreeView>
```

I would expect the subordinate items in the tree to stack horizontally instead of vertically, but I see no visible change when I swap the orientation from `Vertical` to `Horizontal` and back again. Why doesn't the `Orientation` of the `StackPanel` affect the layout of the items in the `ItemsPresenter`?

Comment: Is it possible that you need to retemplate the tree view items' ItemsPresenter themselves? (TreeViewItem.xaml: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/25992?projectName=Silverlight#638164)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Wilcox' comment got me thinking and I figured out what I did wrong. I was modifying the `ItemsPanel` of the `TreeView`, but to achieve what I wanted I had to modify the `ItemsPanel` of the `TreeViewItem`:

```
<controls:TreeView>
  <controls:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:TreeViewItem">
      <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </controls:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Root" IsExpanded="True">
    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Alfa"/>
    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Beta"/>
    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Gamma"/>
  </controls:TreeViewItem>
</controls:TreeView>
```